# Checksum an image in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying to checksum an image, but it takes too long to give a result, tried add values, and Adler-32 but both finishes in a long time (approximately 2 seconds).

Adding values:

```
Function Checksum_CountryFlag(Img : TPicture):Integer;
var j, k, Checksum : Integer;
begin
Checksum := 0;
For j := 0 to Img.Width do
For k := 0 to Img.Height do
If (((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 15577344) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 15311104) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 3816255) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 10526623) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 12303034) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 9013641)) Then
begin
Checksum := Checksum + Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k];
end;
Result := Abs(Checksum);
end;
```

Adler-32:

```
Function Checksum_Adler32(Img : TPicture):Integer;
var i,a,b,j,k : Integer;
begin
a := 1; b := 0;
For j := 0 to Img.Width do
For k := 0 to Img.Height do
If (((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 15577344) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 15311104) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 3816255) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 10526623) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 12303034) And ((Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]) <> 9013641)) Then
begin
a := a + Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k];
b := b + a;
end;
Result := Abs(a) + Abs(b);
end;
```

As you see, i am trying to avoid some values (technical reasons).
Maybe this what makes it takes too long, i don't know, any ideas for improving this algorithm ?

Comment: Why do you skip certian pixels. This way you cannot see the difference when two adjectant pixels one with the ignore color, another without it are swapped.

Comment: Technical reasons, something with the program that i am working on.

Comment: Note that the code examines one pixel too many in both directions.

Comment: i was using Delphi7 and seems that Delphi2007 is faster, is this right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done some correction to make the first version of your code fast:

```
Function Checksum_CountryFlag(Img : TPicture):Integer;
var j, k, Checksum : Integer;
  Line: PLongInt;
begin
  Checksum := 0;
  Img.Bitmap.PixelFormat:= pf32bit; // just for case
  For k := 0 to Img.Height - 1 do begin      //  !! Height first, -1
    Line:= Img.Bitmap.ScanLine[k];
    For j := 0 to Img.Width - 1 do begin  // !! -1
      If ((Line^ <> 15577344) And (Line^ <> 15311104) And (Line^ <> 3816255)
        And (Line^ <> 10526623) And (Line^ <> 12303034) And (Line^ <> 9013641)) Then
        begin
          Checksum := Checksum + Line^;
        end;
      Inc(Line);
    end;
  end;
  Result := Abs(Checksum);
end;
```

---

**Updated:** It gives different result because I fixed a bug in your code (Height-1), (Width-1). I also changed the loop order (external loop by Height) - it is nessessary to use ScanLine. You must do the same corrections in your code before comparing.

Comment: Amazing ! Scanlines are really alot fast, Thanks Serg for the example.

Comment: But it doesn't give the same results.

Comment: Didn't you forget "begin" after the first loop ?

Answer (score 2):

Unroling parts your loop gives much more performance (lig putting img.bitmap.canvas into a variable outside the loops).
Getting the pixel[j,k] to a local variable before the if also helps alot, and it improves readability of the sourcecode.

But the biggest impact might be using the "Scanline" property and getting all pixels in a line to a local vaiable helps even more (you have to switch the height and the width for loops).

Comment: +1 for the scanline property. This really helps but you need to use pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to be sure without a profiler, but looking at that I'd guess that you're losing a lot of time looking up the reader values for `Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k]` repeatedly.

First thing I'd do is save that to a value, like so:

```
pixel := Img.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[j,k];
If ((pixel <> 15577344) And (pixel <> 15311104) And (pixel <> 3816255) And (pixel <> 10526623) And (pixel <> 12303034) And (pixel <> 9013641)) Then
```

That should speed things up significantly.

Comment: yea, you are right, that saved some time but not enough, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Serg' code with corrected (and faster) Pixel value:

```
Function Checksum_CountryFlag(Img : TPicture):Integer;
var j, k, Checksum : Integer;
  Line: PIntegerArray;
  Pixel : integer;
begin
  Checksum := 0;
  Img.Bitmap.PixelFormat:= pf32bit; // just for case
  For k := 0 to Img.Height - 1 do begin      //  !! Height first, -1
    Line:= Img.Bitmap.ScanLine[k];
    For j := 0 to Img.Width - 1 do begin  // !! -1
      Pixel := Line^[j];
      If ((Pixel <> 15577344) And (Pixel <> 15311104) And (Pixel <> 3816255)
        And (Pixel <> 10526623) And (Pixel <> 12303034) And (Pixel <> 9013641)) Then
        begin
          Checksum := Checksum + Pixel;
        end;
      Inc(Line);
    end;
  end;
  Result := Abs(Checksum);
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually faster. How does the benchmarking go?

Comment: It is faster because the pixel value is feched from memory to CPU register only once (before the if statement)