# Checksum on TBitmap in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey, checksum

How do I create a checksum for TBitmap in Firemonkey? (not TPicture).  Preferably directly, and not saving to Streams.

I've done some research on Map that replaces Scanline in Firemonkey...
[How to access TBitmap pixels directly in FMX2 (TBitmap.ScanLine replacement)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185502/how-to-access-tbitmap-pixels-directly-in-fmx2-tbitmap-scanline-replacement)

but still completely lost.  Does anyone have an idea how to use the FMX scanline replacement to do this?

I saw below code for VCL  :

[Checksum an image in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424547/checksum-an-image-in-delphi)

```
Function Checksum_CountryFlag(Img : TPicture):Integer;
var j, k, Checksum : Integer;
  Line: PIntegerArray;
  Pixel : integer;
begin
  Checksum := 0;
  Img.Bitmap.PixelFormat:= pf32bit; // just for case
  For k := 0 to Img.Height - 1 do begin      //  !! Height first, -1
    Line:= Img.Bitmap.ScanLine[k];
    For j := 0 to Img.Width - 1 do begin  // !! -1
      Pixel := Line^[j];
      If ((Pixel <> 15577344) And (Pixel <> 15311104) And (Pixel <> 3816255)
        And (Pixel <> 10526623) And (Pixel <> 12303034) And (Pixel <> 9013641)) Then
        begin
          Checksum := Checksum + Pixel;
        end;
      Inc(Line);
    end;
  end;
  Result := Abs(Checksum);
end;
```

Basically I just need to check if image (in memory) has changed (Width/Height not sufficient as most times the Width/Height do not change even if image has changed), and I prefer not to save to Streams to do a Hash if I can do a direct checksum on FMX TBitmap.

Qn : How do I use the below code to do a checksum on the scanline equivalent?

```
procedure TForm1.btnCompareClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  bd1, bd2 : TBitmapData;
  w,h : Integer;
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('c:\1.jpg');
  Image2.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('c:\2.jpg');
  w := Image1.Bitmap.Width;   
  h := Image1.Bitmap.Height;
  try
    Image1.Bitmap.Map(TMapAccess.Read, bd1);
    Image2.Bitmap.Map(TMapAccess.Write, bd2);
    AlphaColorToScanline(@PAlphaColorArray(bd1.Data)[0], bd2.Data,
    Round(w * h), Image1.Bitmap.PixelFormat);
  finally
    Image1.Bitmap.Unmap(bd1);
    Image2.Bitmap.Unmap(bd2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hash the scan lines. This won't prove that the image is unchanged of course. You'd need to store a copy of the image to do that.

Comment: Checksum nor hash will guarantee the image has not changed. You should keep a copy before doing change and then compare. To speedup things, directly compare scan lines, not each individual pixel.

Comment: yes, I understood that I have to keep a copy of original Bitmap to compare (or at least obtain a hash of original bitmap before discarding it).  How do I do checksum/hash on ScanLine in Firemonkey TBitmap given that ScanLine does not exist?  Thank you.

Comment: You can use the [`Map`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Map) function to get direct access to the bitmap data.

Comment: @GolezTrol I know it's using Map (as shown in my link which I researched) but how do I do a checksum on `AlphaColorToScanLine`?

Comment: `Map` gives you a `TBitmapData`, which exposes a `GetScanline` method. Isn't that what you need? It even gives you the `Data` pointer that points to the whole buffer, so you can get the whole data without going over the individual scanlines. `GetScanLine` is implemented as `Result := Pointer(NativeInt(Data) + I * Pitch);`, so it looks like Data points to a buffer of size `Pitch * Height`, which is probably the same as `Width * Height * BytesPerPixel`.

Comment: @GolezTrol  thanks so much. i'm getting closer. May I ask how to get a Hash or checksum of individual scanlines (without doing has of every pixel)? this aspect of code is entirely new to me. If you could post a small code segment, I'll mark it as the answer so that others can benefit from it too. thanks!